# Wininet does not send parameter

Tags: c++, wininet

I am having very serious problems getting this code to send data to the php server. The c++ application sends data, but instead of it to send the data correctly, it just shows empty fields in the parameters when i view from the database, what could be wrong? My code goes like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Wininet.h>

#define PAGE_NAME "gate.php"

#pragma comment (lib, "wininet")

void compName()
    {
    LPCSTR compName = getenv("COMPUTERNAME");
    printf("Computer name is : %s\n",compName);

    }


void userName()
{
    LPCSTR userName = getenv("USERNAME");
    printf("UserName is : %s\n",userName);

}

void hWid()
{
    HW_PROFILE_INFO hwProfileInfo;
    if(GetCurrentHwProfile(&hwProfileInfo))
    {
    LPCSTR hWid = hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid;
    printf("HWID: %s\n",hWid);
    }
}

void ip()
    {
      HINTERNET hInternet , hFile;
      DWORD rSize;
      char ip[50];
      hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL,INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,NULL,NULL,0);
      hFile = InternetOpenUrlA(hInternet,"http://housenaija.com/ip/ip.php",NULL,0,INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD,0);
      InternetReadFile(hFile,&ip,sizeof(ip),&rSize);
      ip[rSize] ='\0';

      InternetCloseHandle(hFile);
      InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);

     printf("IP adress : %s \n",ip);
    }

void sendPCInfo()
    {
      char hWid[50];
      char compName[50];
      char userName[50];
      char ip[50];
      static TCHAR hdrs[] = TEXT("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      static TCHAR accept[] = "Accept: */*";

      char data[1024];

      // trying to do a concatenation for gate.php?hWid=&compName=&userName=&ip= to save string to Database

      strcpy(data,PAGE_NAME);
      lstrcat(data,"?&hwid=");
      lstrcat(data,hWid);
      lstrcat(data,"&compName=");
      lstrcat(data,(const char*)&compName);
      lstrcat(data,"&userName=");
      lstrcat(data,(const char*)&userName);
      lstrcat(data,"&ip=");
      lstrcat(data,(const char*)&ip);

          //HINTERNET hSession;
          //HINTERNET hConnect;
          //HINTERNET hRequest;

      HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen("AppName",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,NULL,NULL,0);

      HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession,"localhost",80,NULL,NULL,INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP ,0,0);

      HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect,"GET","/pcinfo/gate.php",NULL,NULL,NULL,0,0);

      HttpSendRequest(hRequest,NULL,0,data,strlen(data));

    /*DWORD dwAvailable,dwRead;
      char pOutBuf[1024];
      char* pTempBuf=pOutBuf;
      while(InternetQueryDataAvailable(hRequest,&dwAvailable,0,0) && dwAvailable != 0)
     {
      DWORD dwRead;
      InternetReadFile(hRequest,pTempBuf,dwAvailable,&dwRead);
      pTempBuf += dwRead;
      }
      */

        InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
            InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
                InternetCloseHandle(hSession);

                MessageBox(NULL,"PC Information Sent Successfully","Sent Info",MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OK);

    }


int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
    {
    compName();
    userName();
    hWid();
    ip();
    sendPCInfo();
    system("pause");
    }
```

Edit : The server side that saves to the database looks like this

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "pcinfos";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die ('cannot connect');
mysqli_select_db($con,$db);

$hwid = $_GET['hWid'];
$compName = $_GET['compName'];
$userName = $_GET['userName'];
$ip = $_GET['ip'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO logs (hWid,compName,userName,ip) VALUES ('".$hwid."','".$compName."','".$userName."','".$ip."')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die('Query Failed');

echo "Entry successful";

mysqli_close($con)

?>
```

Comment: We don't see your server-side code, but passing POST data in a GET request looks quite unusual. Are you sure your server does not expect a POST request instead?

Comment: To add to Frederic's above, you don't want "gate.php?" to be a part of posted content. BTW if you might want to convert this to GET HTTP request, in which case you need to pull all parameters into URI and send no body.

Comment: @Roman, i'd be appreciative if you please explain programatically, many thanks, Haemea

Comment: You need URI "http://housenaija.com/ip/ip.php?userName=AAA&compName=BBB&ip=CCC" and no need in `data`. This makes a GET request, and on PHP side you expect it as GET.

Comment: Ok Many thanks , My code Looks like this Now, I uploaded to pastebin, still doesnt send the parameters http://pastebin.com/ba2xrn9H

Comment: In your `sendPCInfo` function, where do the variables you declare for `hWid/compName/etc.` get set?

Comment: how do u mean get set? Please Explain ..txtechelp